# 3d patches from a 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, patch

I have a 3d matrix `(3x3x3)`, and I need to extract 3d patches `(2x2x2)` and transform them in vectors.

In 2d, simply:

`I=randi(5,3,3);`

`2d_patches=im2col(I,[2 2],'sliding');`

What about 3d?

`I=randi(5,3,3,3);`

`3d_patches= ???`

im2col just works in 2d. In 3d I should recombine the vectors `1` and `7`, `2` and `8`, ...
Is there any fast function for this task?

Comment: For 2D case, why I=randi(5,3,3) is a 3D array?

Comment: You can create the 3D version `im2col` by repeatedly calling the 2D `im2col`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is any built-in way to do this. If you need it to be fast, it should be fairly simple to write your own mex-function in c and call it from Matlab.

Here is my (quick and dirty) solution:

### im3col.c:

```
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
  const mxArray *I = prhs[0];
  double *indata = mxGetPr(I);
  double *patchSize = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
  const int *size = mxGetDimensions(I);
  int J = (int)patchSize[0], K = (int)patchSize[1], H = (int)patchSize[2];
  int M = size[0],           N = size[1],           P = size[2];

  int numPatches = (M - J + 1)*(N - K + 1)*(P - H + 1);
  int out_rows = J*K*H, out_cols = numPatches;
  mxArray *out = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( out_rows, out_cols, mxREAL );
  double *outdata = mxGetPr(out);

  int patch = 0;
  for( int h_offset = 0; h_offset < P-H+1; h_offset++ ){
    for( int k_offset = 0; k_offset < N-K+1; k_offset++ ){
      for( int j_offset = 0; j_offset < M-J+1; j_offset++ ){
        int row = 0;
        for( int h = 0; h < H; h++ ){
          for( int k = 0; k < K; k++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < J; j++ ){
              outdata[patch*out_rows + row] = 
                indata[ (j_offset+j) + (k_offset+k)*M + (h_offset+h)*M*N ];
              ++row;
            }}}
      ++patch;
      }}}
  plhs[0] = out;
}
```

### Compile:

```
>> mex -O CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99 -Wall" im3col.c
```

### Test:

```
>> A(:,:,1) = [1,4,7;2,5,8;3,6,9]; A(:,:,2) = [10,13,16;11,14,17;12,15,18];
>> B = im3col(A, [2,2,1])

B =

     1     2     4     5    10    11    13    14
     2     3     5     6    11    12    14    15
     4     5     7     8    13    14    16    17
     5     6     8     9    14    15    17    18

>> A(:,:,1),A(:,:,2)

ans =

     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9


ans =

    10    13    16
    11    14    17
    12    15    18
```

Comment: Not so simple if I ask the question.

Comment: "Simple" assumes you have some experience writing mex functions... I'll try to edit my answer with some code later today.

Comment: Example provided. Is this what you need?

Comment: Very good! It works! My code in matlab was: `[patches3d]=build_patches3d(xi,yi,zi,xp,yp,zp) I=randi(3,xi,yi,zi);

num_patch2d=(xi-xp+1)*(yi-yp+1);
num_patch3d=(xi-xp+1)*(yi-yp+1)*(zi-zp+1);
dim_patch2d=(xp*yp);
dim_patch3d=(xp*yp*zp); 
for count=1:zi
 tmp_patch2d(:,:,count)=im2col(I(:,:,count),[xp yp],'sliding'); 
end 
count=1;
for slice_counter=1:(zi-zp+1)
 for col_patch=1:num_patch2d
  tmp=[];
  for offset=0:(zp-1)
   tmp=vertcat(tmp,tmp_patch2d(:,col_patch,slice_counter+offset));
  end
  patches3d(:,count)=tmp;
  count=count+1;
 end
end`

Comment: Now, I **need the inverse function to restore the original 3d matrix given the 3d_patches**. I know what happens in 2d. Have you any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can reconstruct the original from a subset of the columns of B: just figure out which columns of B correspond to non-overlapping chunks of A.

Comment: Mmh, very mazy. 1)Divide each column of B in chunks, 2)insert each chunk in the corresponding position in the original slice (z dimension), 3)count the number of repetition of overlapping elements, 4)then divide each overlapping element by the number of repetition. I think it should be the algorithm. Are you agree?

Comment: Yes, @no_name you are right. I have posted the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other direction:
(It is pretty slow and there is definitely a faster way)

```
function [img] = patch2im_2d_time(patch, size_img, size_patch, size_skip, border)
Nx = size_img(1);
Ny = size_img(2);
Nt = size_img(5);

psz1 = size_patch(1);
psz2 = size_patch(2);
psz3 = size_patch(3);

%Extract blocks. One could save a lot here.
patches  = reshape(patch, [psz1 psz2 psz3 size(patch,2)]);
c = 1;
img2 = zeros(squeeze(size_img));
%Count for each pixel how many times we added smth to it.
add_count = zeros(size_img);

%The first three loops, loop through all the pixels in the image
for d=1:Nt-psz3+1
    for j=1:Nx-psz2+1
        for i=1:Ny-psz1+1
            %Here we get the next patch. The next patch is always
            %the patch that has the pixel at i,j,d at its top front corner.
            current_patch = patches(:,:,:,c);
            %counter for the next patch
            c = c + 1;
            %In this loop we add the patch values of each pixel in the
            %patch to the image. i,j,d is the base. We add the offset
            %ii jj and dd to it. This iteration takes psz^3 many
            %iterations.
            for dd=1:psz3
                for ii=1:psz2
                    for jj=1:psz1
                        img2(i+ii-1,j+jj-1,d+dd-1) = img2(i+ii-1,j+jj-1,d+dd-1) + current_patch(ii,jj,dd);
                        add_count(i+ii-1,j+jj-1,d+dd-1) = add_count(i+ii-1,j+jj-1,d+dd-1) + 1;
                    end
                end
            end

        end
    end
end
    img = flipud(rot90(img2 ./ add_count,1));
end
```

Remember that MATLAB uses col major.

Answer (score 0):

```
%One possible way to use matlab to call im2col and reshape twice
%N = [row, col, num_frames]

[x_height, ~, num_frames] = size(N);
patchSize = 16;
patchTemporal = 10;

N = reshape(N, x_height, []);

N = im2col(N, [patchSize, patchSize], 'distinct');

N = reshape(N, [], num_frames);

N = im2col(N, [patchSize^2, patchTemporal], 'distinct');
% N = [patchSize^2 *patchTemporal x numPatches]
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guys what about this solution. To obtain 3x3x3 ROIs from I suggest :

```
blkSize=3; % should be a odd value like 3,5,7,etc
r=floor(blkSize/2);
k=1;

for sliceNo=(r+1):(size(I,3)-r)

   img= I(:,:,sliceNo-r:sliceNo+r);

   noPix=(size(img,1)-2*r)*(size(img,2)-2*r);
   neiblk=zeros(blkSize^3,noPix);

   for blk=1:blkSize
       neiblk(blkSize^2*(blk-1)+1:blkSize^2*blk,:)=im2col(img(:,:,blk),...
             [blkSize,blkSize],'sliding');            
   end

   ROIs(:,noPix*(k-1)+1:noPix*k)=neiblk;
   k=k+1;
end
```