# Sum over blocks in a 3D matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, resolution

For a 3N by 3N by 3N matrix A, I would like to derive a N by N by N matrix B whose entries come from summation over blocks in A.

For example, B(1,1,1) = sum of all elements of A(1:3,1:3,1:3).

Basically, A is kind of a high resolution matrix and B is a low resolution matrix from summing over entries in A.

Comment: How general do you want your code to be? Have you tried just using `sum` on the `sum` of `sum`?

Comment: Here's a little benchmark on the working solutions presented here - https://ideone.com/8xeqm7 , take a look! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reshape` + `sum` based approach and as such has to be pretty efficient -

```
sumrows = sum(reshape(A,3,[]),1);                      %// Sum along rows
sumcols = sum(reshape(sumrows,N,3,[]),2);              %// Sum along cols
B = reshape(sum(reshape(sumcols,N*N,3,[]),2),N,N,N);   %// Sum along 3rd dim
```

If you are crazy about one-liners, here's that combining all steps into one -

```
B = reshape(sum(reshape(sum(reshape(sum(reshape(A,3,[]),1),N,3,[]),2),N*N,3,[]),2),N,N,N);
```

Comment: More memory efficient than mine +1

Answer (score 3):

If memory is not a concern, you can use a "labelling" approach: build a 3-component label to group the elements of `A`, and use that label as the first input argument to [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to do the sum. The label uses integers from `1` to `N`, so the result of `accumarray` already has the desired shape (`N`x`N`x`N`).

```
N = 5;
F = 3; %// block size per dimension
A = rand(15,15,15); %// example data. Size FN x FN x FN
[ii jj kk] = ind2sub(size(A), 1:numel(A));
label = ceil([ii.' jj.' kk.']/F);
result = accumarray(label, A(:));
```

Comment: @Simon You are not alone on that :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Simon - Nope.  Definitely not alone!

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D matrix, this would work:

```
B = reshape(sum(im2col(A, [3 3], 'distinct')), [N N]);
```

NB: You need the image processing toolbox.

But for 3D matrices, I don't know of any built-in function equivalent to `im2col`. You might have to use a loop. Left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: Yep, for 3D it looks like you need loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549297/3d-patches-from-a-3d-matrix